# How can I add the text :Phrase+TAB-Key without having Visual Studio 2019 expanding it to <:Phrase></:Phrase>

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, emmet

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 with the Zen Coding addon.

If I'm entering the following text into cshmtl file,

```
:Phrase (+typing the TAB key afterwards)
```

it gets expanded (against my will) to:

```
<:Phrase></:Phrase>
```

This works with any combination of letters, not just 'Phrase'

What is causing this and how can I turn it off?

Please note that I have installed Zen Coding on purpose and want use it for HTML. I just don't want colon+random-word+TAB to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

This "intellisense" is from Zen Coding extension.

[image]

If you want to turn it off, you need to disable the extension in visual studio or contact the author here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding&ssr=false#qna

Comment: I have installed Zen Coding on purpose and want use it for HTML. I just don't want random words to be converted to tags.

Comment: I understand what you want. But the configuration of extension cannot be customized. You need to directly contact the author of "Zen coding" to make it be customized.